# Fastest way to show numbers of users from database?

Tags: .net, mysql

Im doing a COUNT(userid) from my users table and displaying the number on the website but I was wondering if there are any other better way to get, store, and show this info instead of doing one connection and COUNT() from the dabatase everytime a visitor loads a webpage?

**EDIT:**
I just found information about caching at MSDN and this seems to be the absolutle best way to do this, thanks TomTom!

[ASP.NET Caching .NET 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsbfdd8c.aspx)

If I want to populate cachedString with the MembersCount from my database, is this the correct way to to this?

```
    string cachedString;
    cachedString = (string)Cache["CacheItem"];
    if (cachedString == null)
    {
    MySqlConnection Connection = siteStuff.GetConnection();
    MySqlCommand c = new MySqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(id) as TheCount FROM user", Connection);
    Connection.Open();
    MySqlDataReader reader = c.ExecuteReader();
    reader.Read();
    cachedString  = reader["TheCount"].ToString();
    Connection.Close();
    Connection.Dispose();
    Cache.Insert("CacheItem", cachedString);thanks TomTom!
```

**EDIT:** Im currently using this code:

```
    int cacheNumberUsers;
    cacheNumberUsers = (int)Cache["MembersCount"];
    if (cacheNumberUsers == null)
    {
        cacheNumberUsers = siteStuff.GetNumberUsers();
        Cache.Insert("MembersCount", cacheNumberUsers);
    }
    nrRegMembers.Text = cacheNumberUsers.ToString();
```

But im getting the **error**:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

On line:

```
cacheNumberUsers = (int)Cache["MembersCount"];
```

**EDIT:**
I guess I need to insert the item into the cache first?

```
Cache.Insert("MembersCount");
```

But does it matter where I put this code? In other words, shall I just put it in OnLoad so it fires at every page request? Or should I check it it first exists?

Answer (score 0):

Dont make a non database problem a database problem.

As in: cache output of generated pages. Using .NET? use the output cache / partial output cache to return old sql that getsgenerated maybe once per minute or so.

Solving perforamcne issues on the database while ignoring the higher levels is not smart - and for .NET there are wnoderfull output caching mechanisms in all web front end technoloogies. if you woudl say which one you use... I could help you with links.

Comment: Oh.. sorry I have used .NET for about 5 years but Im not really that pro after all..
I would be really thankful if you could give me some good links on how I can cash all sort of stuff so I can speed up my site!
Cash/Partial output cache sounds very interesting!
Any tip on where it's good to apply that on a community wich features uploads of usercreated images, articles and forum posts?

Comment: What .NET technology do you use to generate the web pages?

Comment: Sorry I left that out, it's 4.0

Comment: And still, there are multiple awys to create web pages in 4.0 Which one do you use?

Comment: Well it's a Website, not a Project. If that's what you ment. If not, what do you mean?

Comment: Webforms? MVC? You should know what you use.